# Lenovo X1 Carbon wont boot after install

Tags: boot, lenovo, thinkpad

Ubuntu 18.04 after install I got this.
[image: boot menu]

And if I chose it I got returned to the same thing.

I played with bios options and this is some pictures that I got and I can't make it start ubuntu.
Not sure if need some other options to show here. I try same setup of bios as my main laptop and not working
[image: bios]

[image: bios]

Comment: Sometimes you have to edit the boot option so that the bios/uefi has the right path. Can you check to see what path is on your hard disk and what path the bios is checking for? For example, on my machine the boot option for my hard disk contains the path /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT/ and in that location is the BOOTX64.efi file.

Comment: I found one similar problem like this. At the point of Linux install, the laptop idea was for dual boot. I deleted old EFI part [ 512 mb] and created new one then reinstall ubuntu [ on separated partition ] and during update-grub, he fixed it.

Weird is that same bios setup is on my laptop but single boot on linux. žweird =\

Comment: @dMatija I have done this many times. Every single time the solution was for me to boot up from the Ubuntu installation USB/disc, delete all the partitioning and install again. Dual-booting on the same disk is asking for problems, it's much more reliable to install a single OS per disk. I do that successfully with Ubuntu and other versions of Linux all the time. Specifically I have done this with my Lenovo X1E.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, disabling the security chip worked for me.

I went to BIOS Settings --> Security --> Security Chip --> Disable

Now my system boots with no issues.

Comment: Hi Dale, it sounds much more likely that when installing Ubuntu, OP did something to break the bootloader...