I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my laptop Thinkpad X1 carbon 4th gen. But immediately after the installation it always reboots. "Reset System"
As it's not showing anything I can't provide any more images or something. BIOS is updated to the latest.

Does it ask for reboot only one time just after install or all the time ?

Do you get any error messages and/or log output at all? Perhaps you should try a serial connection: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelDebuggingTricks

This might help https://askubuntu.com/questions/1215989/lenovo-x1-carbon-wont-boot-after-install

It always reboots continuously.

How was it installed? Where did you get the install ISO from? How was the bootable media built? There is a lot more detail you can give.

When do you get "Reset System" can you enter bios? is it password protected? you need to give more info, did you change anything in bios? etc. Do not add to comments edit your question with all the info, even those asked by David.

Recreate a bootable USB from the official image. It looks like the bootable USB is not working as it needs to be.

I did, but it's not happening. Tried other distros too. Using Rufus and balena etcher. If there is any specific method to recreate and burn, please share.
